# Google App Engine Static Website Handler Wildcard Routes

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a React.js website using create-react-app and just moved from Firebase Hosting to Google App Engine Standard Environment.

With Firebase Hosting, I could create routes like https://example.com/route or  https://example.com/newRoute/123 and Firebase would know to serve the index.html for any of these routes.

I want to wildcard any route of our application to use the index.html while excluding .js and .css files. If I use only the wildcard /(.*) then the request for our main.js file also resolves to index.html.

Here is our handler config

```
handlers:
  - url: /
    secure: always
    application_readable: false
    static_files: build/index.html
    require_matching_file: false
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /login
    secure: always
    application_readable: false
    static_files: build/index.html
    require_matching_file: false
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: '/(.*)'
    secure: always
    application_readable: false
    static_files: "build/\\1"
    require_matching_file: false
    upload: 'build/.*'
```

In the current configuration, every route I create must be registered as a handler. I was hoping to find a solution where all current routes and future routes can be handled by a wildcard.

Comment: is it always the `build/index.html` that you want to upload?

Comment: yes. I want to always upload `build/index.html` except for when index.html makes the request for our static assets (js, css, png, jpg, svg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the handlers matters, the 1st one with a matching pattern wins.

So to achieve what you want you could handle the exceptions first, before "wildcarding" the `index.html`. Something along these lines (I assumed the `.css` and `.js` files are also relative to the `build` dir):

```
handlers:

  - url: /(.*\.css)$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.css$

  - url: /(.*\.js)$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.js$

  # continue similarly the other static assets
  # or maybe try a more generic one covering several of them:
  - url: /(.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg))$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg)$

  # wildcard everything else, serving index.html
  - url: '/(.*)'
    secure: always
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Side note: for readability I also dropped the `require_matching_file` (no such thing in GAE) and `application_readable` (by default it is false).

Comment: `require_matching_file` isn't documented, but is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Dan still does it.
The only addition I had to implement was for fonts extension in the 3rd handler.
As a FYI, I am using this config for a Vue 3 app and the default build settings.

Final app.yaml for me:

```yaml
handlers:

  - url: /(.*\.css)$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.css$

  - url: /(.*\.js)$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.js$

  # continue similarly the other static assets
  # or maybe try a more generic one covering several of them:
  - url: /(.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg|woff|woff2|ttf))$
    secure: always
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)$

  # wildcard everything else, serving index.html
  - url: '/(.*)'
    secure: always
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```